# I can't use <nameofmystructure>* this as an argument to a function

Tags: c

this is the code i'm having trouble with:

```
typedef const char* sun_date_t;
typedef const char* sun_time_t;

typedef struct sun_t {
  int luminosity;

  /* private */
  sun_date_t date;
  sun_time_t time;
  sun_time_t sunrise;
  sun_time_t sunset;

  pthread_t tid;
  pthread_mutex_t mutex;
} sun_t;

void sun_parse_data (sun_t* this, FILE* f){.....}
```

as you see, i define an structure and after i try to pass it as a pointer to this "sun_t", but the compiler says i need to write ',' or '....' before 'this'. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: C or C++? Maybe the compiler thinks `this` is a keyword?

Comment: @KarolS compiling as C works fine but compiling as C++ in gcc generates the same error.

Answer (score 2):

You must be compiling as C++ since `this` is a [keyword in C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword) in [C it is not](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/keyword) but it is probably not a good idea to use `this` as a variable name in case you want to port the code later on.

The code compiles fine as a C program: [see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d52b843ff552384) but we see the same error when we attempt to compile as a C++ program: [see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/713661afbef41538):

> error: expected ',' or '...' before 'this'